# Find the median from a stream of integers

Tags: algorithm

Given an unsorted sequence of integers that flows into your program as a stream.

The integers are too many to fit into memory.

Imagine there is a function:

```
int getNext() throws NoSuchElementException;
```

It returns the next integer from the stream.

Write a function to find the median.

Solve the problem in O(n).

Any ideas?

Hint is given (use heap the data structure..)

Comment: Oops maxed out on votes today

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378506/probability-of-finding-the-median-with-finite-space

Comment: Was this question asked by a Googler?

Comment: Or [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579912/how-do-i-find-the-median-of-numbers-in-linear-time-using-heaps). Which also references prior SO questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [paper](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~suri/cs290/MunroPat.pdf).  It will (likely) take more than one pass.  The idea is that in each pass upper and lower bounds are computed such that the median lies between them.

A fundamental result here is *N* = size of data, *P* = number of passes

Theorem 2) A *P*-pass algorithm which selects the *K*<sup>th</sup> highest of *N* elements requires
storage at most *O(N<sup>(<sup>1</sup>/<sub>P</sub>)</sup>(log N)<sup>(2-<sup>2</sup>/<sub>P</sub>)</sup>)*.

Also, for very small amounts of storage *S*, i.e., for *2 <= S <= O((log N)<sup>2</sup>)*, there is a class of selection algorithms which use
at most *O((log N)<sup>3/S</sup>)* passes.

Read the paper.  I'm not really sure what the heap has to do with it

Comment: Seems a bit heavy for an interview question.

Comment: I suspect that the purpose of the interview question was to figure out how the interviewee approached problems, and not to find a solution.  (At least I hope so.)

Answer (score 10):

You have to maintain two heaps one max heap ( which contains the smallest N/2 elements seen till now) and one min heap ( which contains the largest N/2 elements). Store the extra element aside if N is odd.

Whenever you call the function getNext(),

If N becomes odd, save the new element as the extra element.  If necessary, exchange that element with one from the min-heap or max-heap to satisfy the following condition

max(max-heap) <= extra element <= min(min-heap).

If N becomes even, do the same as above to get a 2nd extra element.  Then, add the smaller one to the max-heap and the larger one to the min-heap.
Insert should be O(log N)

Get Median: O(1)
If N is odd, the median is the extra element.
If N is even, the median is the average between the tops of the 2 heaps

Comment: How would you cater to "the integers are too many to fit in memory"?

Comment: Not to mention the O(n) time constraint.  Even with a Fibonacci heap the running time will be O(n lg n)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the window for the median to maintain is K. 
Construct a binary search tree for K number. O(K);
Do in-order traversal and find the (K/2)th element.O(K/2);

The overall time is O(K).

Answer (score 0):

Using selection algorithm, we can achieve this in O(n) complexity. But I still dont understand the use of a Heap in this case clearly.