# concat multiple big files from on directory causes memory error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to concate 50 txt files from one directory, each of them does have >300 MB. The function below does work for two of these files but not for all them. I am quite new to python and therefore I am not sure if my function  could be faster. I already cheacked similar topics but couldn't find a better way. Do you have an idea how to make it more efficient?

my script to concat files:

```
def txtComponentstoOne(rdire):
    path=rdire
    allFiles=glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.txt"))
    df = pd.concat((pd.read_table(f, header=None, dtype={0:str,1:int,2:int,3:str, 4:str, 5: int, 6:int}) for f in allFiles),ignore_index=True)
    return df
```

My overall aim is to calculate the median of column 6 for each row with the same values in the other columns. Thus, if you know how to do that without concate the files before, it would also solve my problem.

Comment: If you need _exact_ values for the median you will need to store basically all the data, or at least half of it (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372006/incremental-median-computation-with-max-memory-efficiency)). If you can live with an _estimation_ of the median values there may be some incremental approaches that don't require you to have everything in memory at the same time. You can also do one column at a time (loading only one column), if that is enough data reduction.

Comment: If you only use part of the data from each frame you should definitly filter the data right after loading each file, and only then concatenate it in a single frame.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to filter the data before concatenate, because the file slightly differ in size I assume that do not share the same number of lines. I was thinking about combining columns 0-5 to one column. Would that change the size in any way?

Comment: I managed to combine the files on a Linux server with  'cat *> mergedfile.txt' (16GB) But I'm still looking for a way to get the median depending on the other columns. in python I used groupby()[6].median()