# pandas - compute median / percentile from a large csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv file, millions of rows. So I use `chunksize` to read them to preserve memory.

I can compute the sum of a col `bytes_alloc` as below.

```
tf = pd.read_csv("../Samples/analytics/trace.csv", chunksize=1024*25)

tot_mem_usage = 0
for tf in df:
  tot_mem_usage += df.sum()["bytes_alloc"]
```

How do I go about computing the median or other percentiles across multiple chunks ?

Comment: I do not believe the median can be easily computed incrementally. You may want to have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372006/incremental-median-computation-with-max-memory-efficiency

Comment: If the data on your files consist of a not-so-large subset of integer numbers, you can bin it ("construct a histogram") and then calculate the median from the bins.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to calc the `mean`, you may take a look at [Blaze (Pandas interface to Big Data)](https://github.com/blaze/blaze).

You have nearly no read time (see talk at [PyData](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tcb2-sOU76M)):

[image: Read Time of a 10GB csv file]

and Blaze supports simple operations like `.mean()` on the DataFrame:

[image: Calculation of the mean of a 10GB file]